# Getting risk free rate for CAPM using Quantmod (R) for analysis of 5 year stock returns

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I have been looking online but can't find a specific example/answer to my question. I am using the Quantmod and PerformanceAnalytics libraries to calculate the alpha and beta of a portfolio using the CAPM functions. But I don't want to assume Rf = 0. I would like to get the actual/historical risk free rate.

I could get the 5-Year Treasury Constant Maturity Rate (DGS5) or 5-Year Treasury Constant Maturity Rate (GS5) from FRED (not quite sure if there's a difference between them), but how do I get Rf from that value? Is it just the average?  Thanks.

Or am I completely off :(.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hi, I think this question is more related to theory rather than a specific programming question. Your question may be better suited at http://quant.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the 90-day or 30-day Treasury Bill is used as the risk free rate and can be downloaded like so ( here I use the 90-day bill) :

```
library(quant mod)
getSymbols('DGS3MO',src = 'FRED’)

> tail(DGS3MO)
           DGS3MO
2016-10-18   0.34
2016-10-19   0.35
2016-10-20   0.35
2016-10-21   0.34
2016-10-24   0.33
2016-10-25   0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from hvollmeier is great, but it does not go all the way in providing risk-free rates. However, you can use data such as 'DGS3MO' in this Python workflow that can be translated to R easily:

[Computing Risk Free Rates and Excess Returns from Zero-Coupon-Bonds](https://developers.refinitiv.com/en/article-catalog/article/computing-risk-free-rates-and-excess-returns-from-zero-coupon-bonds)

Granted, it is in Python... In there you can find the following function and a full explanation of the theory:

```
def ZCB_YTM_Implied_r_f(YTM, Maturity, D):
    """
    This Python function returns the Zero-Coupn Bond (ZCB) Yield To Maturity (YTM) Implied Risk Free Interest Rate, thus its name 'ZCB_YTM_Implied_r_f'
    
    YTM (Datastream pandas dataframe): The Yield To Maturity of the Zero-Coupon Bond in question.
    It requiers the DSWS library from Refinitiv.
    E.g.: YTM = ds.get_data(tickers = 'TRUS1MT', fields = "X", start = '1950-01-01', freq = 'D')/100
    
    Maturity (float): The number of years until the bond matures.
    This can be lower than 1, e.g.: One-Month Zero-Coupon Treasury Bill would have a 'Maturity' value of 1/12.
    E.g.: Maturity = 1/12
    
    D (int): The number of time periods (e.g.: days) until the bond matures
    N.B.: The 1-, 2-, and 3-month rates are equivalent to 30-, 60-, and 90-day dates respectively, as reported on the Board's Commercial Paper Web page.
    E.g.: D = 30
    """
    
    # Rename the columns of 'YTM' correctly:
    instrument_name = YTM.columns[0][0]
    arrays = [[instrument_name],['YTM']]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    YTM.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Instrument', 'Field'])
    
    # Calculate the r_f
    r_f = ((YTM + 1)**(1/D))-1
    
    # Rename the columns of r_f correctly:
    instrument_name = YTM.columns[0][0]
    arrays = [[instrument_name],['YTM_Implied_r_f']]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    r_f.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Instrument', 'Field'])
    
    # return a list including r_f 0th and YTM 1st.
    return(r_f, YTM)
```